# Check if join point is null on Spring AOP

Tags: spring-aop

I´m developing an aspect using spring aop.

We usually use JoinPoint as object to retrieve class name, method name, ...

I´m doing this:

```
String className = joinPoint.getTarget() != null && joinPoint.getTarget().getClass() != null && joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() != null ? joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName() : "";
String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature() != null && joinPoint.getSignature().getName() != null ? joinPoint.getSignature().getName() : "";
```

I have to do this? I never on tutorials or projects do this. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

How can a joinPoint be null. 
The reason an advice gets called is because its pointcut has matched with a method and the advice gets executed. So, There's no point in checking if its null.

It's like this.

```
boolean isInteger(int a) {
    if(a is an Integer) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

see there's no point of this function. Checking if joinpoint is null falls under the same style.